# Fetching data issue

Tags: php

I am trying to implement search with different dropdown filters (Grade, School, Team, Students) but something is going terribly wrong with my code. When i load the page "retrieve1.php", i am able to see only one box i.e. Grade and that is also empty. I would appreciate any help. Below is my code -

```
<?php
require 'account1.php';
echo "<body style='background-color:#DCDCDC'>";

$sql= "SELECT * FROM bpi_registration LEFT JOIN bpi_schoolInfo on 
bpi_registration.id_school = bpi_schoolInfo.id_school ";
$query=$db->query($sql);


function grade() {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_classInfo');
    while($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['class_name'] . "'>" . $row['class_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function school() {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_schoolInfo');
    while($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['school_name'] . "'>" . $row['school_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function team() {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_teamProfile');
    while($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['team_name'] . "'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function students() {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_registration');
    while($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id']. "'>" . $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']. "</option>"; 
    }
}
?>

<form action="retrieve1.php" method="GET">
    <select name="Grade">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Grade</option>
        <?php grade() ?>
    </select>

    <select name="School">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose School</option>
        <?php school() ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Team">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Team</option>
    <?php team() ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Students">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Students</option>
        <?php students() ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<table width="600" border="2">  
    <tr>  
        <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
        <th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
        <th width="97"> <div align="center">State </div></th>  
        <th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>   
    <tr>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['Students'])) 
{
    //echo $_GET['Students'];
    $userQuery = "{$sql} WHERE bpi_registration.id = :user_id";
    $user = $db->prepare($sql);
    $user->execute(['user_id' => $_GET['Students']]);
    $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($selectedUser))
{
    echo $selectedUser['email'];
    echo $selectedUser['address_city']; 
    echo $selectedUser['address_state']; 
    echo $selectedUser['address_country']; 
}
?>
```

account1.php

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',$user, $pass);
?>
```

I get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null 
 in public_html/retrieve1.php on line 24
```

Comment: So what does your sites markup look like? Use your browsers function to display the "source" of the page it loaded.

Comment: Also you _always_ want to monitor your http servers error log file. That is where you can see exactly if something is wrong with your php scripts without having to _guess_ what _might_ happen or not.

Comment: @arkascha i am not getting any error. The only thing that i see is one empty "grade" box when i load "retrieve1.php"

Comment: Inspect your page, can you see your select boxes there? Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: As said: take a look at your pages source code inside the browser. I assume you did as I suggested, so what do you see?

Comment: @Epodax so i did inspect the page and only box i see is "Grade". How do i check error reporting ? I am new to PHP

Comment: You are not seeing any errors because you are not looking for them. Either look at your `PHP Error log` or Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i added that line and tried to reload the page i don't see any error

Comment: Also show us what is in `'account1.php'`

Comment: I also see a major issue with **scope**! `$db` will not be available in any of your functions. It needs to be passed as a parameter to each function eg `function grade($db)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have updated my post with account1.php upcourse i have removed the actual db credentials but this is how the generic code for account1.php looks like

Comment: Also move the first query down inside the `if (isset($_GET['Students']))` where it is actually being used. Leaving a `->query()` dangaling un-processed may be blocking the PDO object

Comment: Let's stop this! @jondoe you have to learn to do your homework! Above you claim: "i am not getting any error". So we assume you did check your error log file as you were asked. Now it turns out that obviously you did not bother to do that! You code will definitely throw an error in each function, since `$db` is _not_ an object in there. Why don't you simply take a look into your error log file?

Comment: @arkascha sir i am simply using "textwrangler" as a text editor. As RiggsFolly suggested i included that line in my code at the top then i reload the page. Now the error log file that you are referring i am not sure how to check that. If you can tell me how to check it i would love to learn and also share the errors that i am getting.

Comment: Also you want to be using `$db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` as this returns one row at a time and works in a while loop. `->fetchAll` returns an ARRAY and will not work in a WHILE loop

Comment: It is perfectly fine if you don't know all details that might be involved here. We all learn, all the time. But please ask in that case. Just claiming some reply without mentioning that you did not understand the question is not a good idea. As a php developer one of the first things you have to learn is to monitor the error log file your http server writes. That is where you can simply _read_ what is wrong instead of having to guess and start a discussion like this one. The typical location of that log file is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, check your configuration if in doubt.

Comment: Basically this code need a complete rewrite and that is not the function of SO. [Start by reading the manual for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [PHP Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @arkascha ah i see i would have to dig this deeply as i m working on college server

Comment: The configuration of the http server pretty certain is readable by all accounts (read access, not write access). And also I am sure your college will love to assist you with looking into the error log file, _if_ they have an interest in educating students.

Comment: If you have added the debug code I suggested you must be getting errors. If you have a complex page it may be being obsquired by other HTML. Look at the page-source and see if you see the errors hidden in the HTML

Comment: @RiggsFolly One could simply add to inject `$db` into all functions in this script to get it working.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry I dont follow you, so I doubt that the questioner will either?

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for grade(), called in public_html/retrieve1.php on line 94 and defined in <b>/public_html/retrieve1.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: db in <b>public_html/retrieve1.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was a side remark: you claimed "this code need a complete rewrite". I replied to that by mentioning that although that is an option and maybe a good one, there is no reason why one _has to_ do that. One certainly can get that script to work by injecting the database object into the functions where it is to be used. Simple, working, and probably helping the OP to understand the issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i looked page-source and posted some errors that i m getting

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have used $db as a parameter in all functions as u suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you report is due to a variable scoping issue. In other words the functions do not know what `$db` is because it is  out of scope, `$db` exists in the global scope but not in each functions scope.

Also a `->FetchAll()` will return an array, if you are using a while loop to process the result set from a query you should use `->fetch()` as this will return one row per call and is usable in a while loop.

Also the first query you ran, and then later attempted to amend the search criteria on will not work. Once a `->query()` has been called the query cannot be amended. So I moved that code to where it was actually being used and removed the unnecessary call to `->query()`

I also added some table line HTML to your output so the data will fit into the table structure.

The amended code below should move you towards your goal, or the next error.

```
<?php
require 'account1.php';
echo "<body style='background-color:#DCDCDC'>";

function grade($db) {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_classInfo');
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['class_name'] . "'>" . $row['class_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function school($db) {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_schoolInfo');
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['school_name'] . "'>" . $row['school_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function team($db) {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_teamProfile');
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['team_name'] . "'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}

function students($db) {
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bpi_registration');
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id']. "'>" . $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']. "</option>"; 
    }
}
?>

<form action="retrieve1.php" method="GET">
    <select name="Grade">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Grade</option>
        <?php grade($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="School">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose School</option>
        <?php school($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Team">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Team</option>
    <?php team($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Students">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Students</option>
        <?php students($db) ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>

<table width="600" border="2">  
    <tr>  
        <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
        <th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
        <th width="97"> <div align="center">State </div></th>  
        <th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>   
    </tr>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['Students'])) 
{
    $sql= "SELECT * 
           FROM bpi_registration 
             LEFT JOIN bpi_schoolInfo on 
                       bpi_registration.id_school = bpi_schoolInfo.id_school ";


    //echo $_GET['Students'];
    $userQuery = "{$sql} WHERE bpi_registration.id = :user_id";
    $user = $db->prepare($sql);
    $user->execute(['user_id' => $_GET['Students']]);
    $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($selectedUser))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_city'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_state'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>
    }
}
echo '</table>`;
?>
```

Comment: This was a great help. I appreciate that you shared those documentation that i can refer to study those material. It will help me a lot.